# Why the program is not executing in proper way?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

The program is not executing as it should execute . When I input the elements    it takes more than 12 elements which should not happen . Please tell me if there is anything wrong in the code . I am trying to output three 2D arrays separately .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    int abc[2][2][3]; // three 2D arrays declared .

    for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                cin >> *(*(*(abc + k) + i) + j); // entering the element abc[i][j][k].
            }
        }
    }

    // REQUIRED 3D ARRAY .
    for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                cout << *(*(*(abc + k) + i) + j) << "       ";
            } // respective 2d arrays are printed .
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: *The program is not executing as it should execute* -- Yes it is -- the program is doing exactly what you wrote.

Comment: *Please tell me if there is anything wrong in the code* - you tell me, is there anything wrong with it? What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

`*(*(*(abc + k) + i) + j)` is `abc[k][i][j]`.

You're indexing outside of the array, which is undefined (you're most likely overwriting the index variables).

An array of 3 2x2 arrays would be `abc[3][2][2]` – which would be correct for your loop.

(Don't use pointer arithmetic when you're working with arrays, it's only confusing.)